# Anusasanika Parva is it a mistranslation?

Tags: mahabharata, translation

Has the Anusasanika Parva been mistranslated, it's the long speech where Bhishma talks to Yudishtara. Is the tone somehow changed? This is for English translations. I am using the Mahabharata found in Wisdom Library. Here is the link: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan

Comment: Thanks for visiting HSE. What leads you to believe that the translation is inauthentic? Did you see this claim somewhere? If so, and if it's online, please link it here so we can have more context. If you yourself believe that this is the case, and have concluded so based on a change in literary style, do explain your reasoning. There are many, many translations of the Mahabharata out there; which specific one are you doubting? Have you read the Sanskrit versions, and do you see discrepancies? If you [edit] to add details, it would be helpful.

Comment: You told me to separate my question, so I did...

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's also helpful that you added the WisdomLib link. FWIW, _I_ think that it's a pretty good translation, if a little old, but I'm not an expert. I do agree that there is a subtle shift in the tone at that point, but I'm not sure if it indicates mistranslation or something else.

Comment: KMG translation is usually good. I have never seen anyone claim any parva in KMG to be a mistranslation.

Comment: translations are subject to opinions. Please read forum rules